# Problemas sobre Python y mariadb code=3221225477

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, mariadb

al realizar la consulta, solo me recupera primera fila, el codigo es el siguiente

```
from email.mime import application
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import ttk
import mariadb

class ReporteCaja:
    def __int__(self,ventana):
        self.ventana=ventana
        self.ventana.title("Hola Mundo")
        marco=LabelFrame(self.ventana,text="ReporteCaja")
        marco.grid(row=0,column=1)
        #nombre
        Label(marco,text="Nombre").grid(row=0,column=0)
        Entry(marco).grid(row=0,column=1)
        #clave
        Label(marco,text="Clave").grip(row=1,column=0)
        Entry(marco).grid(row=1,column=1)
        #Boton
        ttk.Button(marco,text="Guardar Alumno").grip(row=2,columnspan=2,sticky=W+E)
        
    def consulta(self,query):
        try:
            conn=mariadb.connect(
                host="host",
                user="automaton",
                password="****",
                database="prueba"
            )
        except mariadb.Error as identifer:
            print("Error al conectar al DB")
        
        cur=conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(query)
        return cur
    
    def mostrarDatos(self):
        cur=self.consulta("select Name from User ")
        for (Name) in cur:
            print(Name)
        
if __name__=="__main__":
    ventana=Tk()
    application=ReporteCaja()
    application.mostrarDatos()
    ventana.mainloop()
```

dicha tabla tiene 160 filas pero solo logro imprimir 17 filas de ella luego finaliza el codigo, en VSC suele salir el error [Done] exited with code=3221225477, la verdad ni idea de donde mirar, si tienen alguna idea de ello, o de por ahi si estoy cometiendo una feroz novatada

Comment: Hice la prueba en una db local y no me da el error. No necesariamente sea la causa, pero la línea `from email.mime import application` esté entrando en conflicto con lo de casi al final: `application=ReporteCaja()`. Renombra alguna de las 2 instrucciones para resolver esa colisión de nombres.

Comment: Buenas como andamos?, ahora hice la modificacion y pareceria mentira pero no, sigue el problema, como comentaste te pudo imprimir sin drama varias lineas, y la verdad, ahora mi consulta seria si con una nueva instalacion de python las varias como esa cur que uso, tendrian alguna limitacion de almacenamiento de datos?